# How do I return an object from a dialog when using WindowManager in Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm just starting out with the Caliburn Micro WindowManager.

I have managed to display a modal dialog containing my WPF view.

I need to return an object from the dialog. What is the best way to do this?

Background - this is a login dialog. I need to validate the username and password and return user configuration information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to do this. I'm assuming your Login viewmodel class derives from Caliburn.Micro.Screen.

1) Have the view model (representing your login screen) expose a property that returns the user configuration. You can then access it upon a successful login like below:

```
var windowManager = new WindowManager();
var login = new MyLoginViewModel();
if (windowManager.ShowDialog(login) == true)
{
    var configurationInfo = login.MyUserConfigurationInfo;
}
```

2) Add the user configuration information to the application's resource dictionary upon a successful login. The example below shows you setting this inside a "Login" method inside the login viewmodel.

```
void Login()
{
    /* Authentication Logic success */
    App.Current.Resources["UserConfigurationInfo"] = new UserConfigurationInfo();
    TryClose(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Your first suggestion looks best. How do I set the result on window manager from login view model so that I can test for true?

Comment: It would work just like the second option except you set the property instead of some application resource. Essentially, when the user authenticates inside the LoginViewModel, you'd set the LoginViewModel's "MyUserConfigurationInfo" property at that point to an instance of that type.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know Caliburn Micro WindowManager but if your modal dialog view has a viewmodel, what about to just take the viewmodel where you can access your object?

in my project a have a ILoginViewModel which i use after DialogResult=true in my app.cs. (i export this information with MEF, so its easy to access for my moduls)